# Typeahead problems with Bootstrap 3.0 RC1

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) with Bootstrap 3 RC1, because Bootstrap dropped its own typeahead plugin on version 3.

I'm using the following HTML on my form:

```
<div class="well">  
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="query">Search:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Start typing something to search...">              
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Without adding Typeahead, the search input field displays like this:

[image: before adding Typeahead]

Then I added Typeahead like this:

```
<script>
    $('#query').typeahead({        
        local: ['alpha', 'bravo','charlie','delta','epsilon','gamma','zulu']
    });
</script>
```

And the field became smaller, with a white rectangle inside it.

[image: after adding Typeahead]

[image: when typing some text...]

**Am I doing something wrong or it's just a bug on Typeahead or Bootstrap 3 RC1?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS issue on Twitter Typeahead with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059161/css-issue-on-twitter-typeahead-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Although support has been dropped you can use the "old" plugin https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**update 14 feb 2014**

As mentioned by [laurent-wartel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408100/laurent-wartel) try https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less or https://github.com/bassjobsen/typeahead.js-bootstrap-css for additional CSS to use typeahead.js with Bootstrap 3.1.0.

Or use use the "old" (TB 2) plugin with the new Bloodhound suggestion engine: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/26

---

Twitter's typeahead doesn't seem ready for Twitter's Bootstrap 3.
To use Twitter's typeahead with Twitter's Bootstrap you will need [some extra CSS](https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css) (deprecated, no longer maintained).
Using this CSS doesn't fix your problems.

In your example the input field don't get a 100% width. This will be cause by the Javascript. The javascript wraps the input in a span:

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead" 
    style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr;">
```

This span don't got a 100% so do input inside it. To fix add to your CSS:

```
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The Javascript sets the background-color of your input to transparent. If you don't want to change the plugin source i will need some additional Javascript to fix this:

```
$('.tt-query').css('background-color','#fff');
```

<strike>Now is should work as expected based on your example. http://www.bootply.com/73439</strike>

**update**

The original question was for RC1 for Twitter's Bootstrap 3.0.0. you also need to add:

```
.tt-dropdown-menu {
   width:100%;        
}
```

New bootply: http://bootply.com/86305

Comment: In addition, you might want to add .tt-hint to that CSS, otherwise the hint is cut off at the original width, so: `.twitter-typeahead, .tt-hint {
    width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less).

It works great with the latest version of Bootstrap (v3.0.3) and allows you to keep your custom theming. There is also a .css file with default bootstrap theming.

Answer (score 1):

Typeahead.js css fixing also have problems with input groups (corners rounding), i found somewhere info that it breaks on modals, etc.
Additionaly https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css is no longer mantained so i am going to give a try for Bass Jobsen solution ;)

Comment: After spending a few hours best replacement for me is
https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead
(for ajax json arrays), nicely working with bs 3.0.3. I will need to check css fixing, but should work easily as dropdown generation templates are easily accesible.
(of course .typeahead.dropdown-menu { width: 100% } is required :D)

there is 1 error in examples for ajax, showLoadingMask don't work (BS 2 artifact?)

unfortunately no caching for requests yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research with no luck at all adding styles, I finally fixed it adding one line inside the constructor Typeahead (bootstrap.js or bootstrap-typeahead.js depending on your version):

this.$menu.width(this.$element.outerWidth());

Here's the code:

```
/* TYPEAHEAD PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
 * ================================= */

var Typeahead = function (element, options) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.typeahead.defaults, options)
    this.matcher = this.options.matcher || this.matcher
    this.sorter = this.options.sorter || this.sorter
    this.highlighter = this.options.highlighter || this.highlighter
    this.updater = this.options.updater || this.updater
    this.source = this.options.source
    this.$menu = $(this.options.menu)
    this.shown = false
    this.listen()
    this.$menu.width(this.$element.outerWidth());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead Twitter Typeahead, try to use [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select). This library is integrated into the Bootstrap 3 and has a wider functionality.

Comment: The bootstrap-select linked is not a replacement for a typeahead autocompletion. They serve different purposes.

Comment: I think it can be, especially using second [version of this lib (select2)]( http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)