# Javascript with Twitter's typeahead.js ruining my form's layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, typeahead.js

So I have a script that uses the typeahead to pull up data from my database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navPersonSearch").typeahead({
    name: 'people',
    remote: 'name_autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
  })
    .keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is what my form looks like without the script
[image: No script]

And this is what it looks like with the script:[image: with script]

This is the html on the page (using bootstrap 3):

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">Search</h1>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
             <form id="search_form" align="center" action="/search/" class="form-inline" method ="get" role="form">
           <input id="navPersonSearch" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q"
            placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress"
                 autocomplete="off" >
      </form> 
      </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div>  <!-- /.row -->
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div> <!-- /.jumbotron -->
```

I'm not sure why the script is messing with my form's layout.

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/378
Some people have made fixes for it, but you may need to rearrange your form for the fix to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typeahead problems with Bootstrap 3.0 RC1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167246/typeahead-problems-with-bootstrap-3-0-rc1)

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it looks like this is a known issue with Bootstrap 3: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/378

People have made some fixes to it, but the fixes aren't completely universal, you'd have to tweak the properties yourself to actually get it to work properly. The fix that I'm starting off with is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ragulka/Dy9au/1/

```
.twitter-typeahead {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #c09853;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #b94a48;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  border-color: #468847;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-warning .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #a47e3c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #dbc59e;
}
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-error .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #953b39;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
}
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-query:focus,
.has-success .twitter-typeahead .tt-hint:focus {
  border-color: #356635;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #7aba7b;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  color: #a1a1a1;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query {
  z-index: 2;
}
.twitter-typeahead .tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .tt-hint {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
}
.twitter-typeahead .input-sm.tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .hint-sm.tt-hint {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.twitter-typeahead .input-lg.tt-query,
.twitter-typeahead .hint-lg.tt-hint {
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px !important;
}
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-query,
.input-group .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0 !important;
}
.input-sm.tt-query,
.hint-sm.tt-hint,
.input-group.input-group-sm .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-sm .tt-hint {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:first-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px !important;
}
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .twitter-typeahead:last-child .tt-hint {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0 !important;
}
.input-lg.tt-query,
.hint-lg.tt-hint,
.input-group.input-group-lg .tt-query,
.input-group.input-group-lg .tt-hint {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.tt-suggestion {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor a {
  color: #fff;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```