# typeahead on bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Currently I'm using [this typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) but it display like this:

[image]

Ist possible to display the typeahead, same width as the `input`?

What I tried so far is:

```
.dropdown-menu {    
    display: block; position: static; width: 100%; 
}
```

But this break the lower fields

[image]

Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7wLF/)

**UPDATE:**

I tried both of @neel shah and @shin solution and this is the result. I don't know why in the fiddle is not looking this way

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/J4Emc/). Hope it helps.

```
.dropdown-menu { width: 100%; }
```

UPDATE:
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18171568/3518203) out.

Comment: please see the accepted answer it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18171568/3518203

Comment: In the end I used the accepted answer on @shin's comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `position: static` you just need to remove it from the css

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t7wLF/2/)

```
.dropdown-menu { display: block; width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({})
on('typeahead:opened',function(){$('.dropdown-menu').css('width',$('.typeahead').width() + 'px');});
```

Comment: I tried this with this code `$('#itemLaborCode').typeahead({name: 'example',source: ['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6']}).on('typeahead:opened',function(){$('.dropdown-menu').css('width',$('#itemLaborCode').width() + 'px');
 });` but still not working

Comment: The event is not firing I tested it. Can you give more detail?

Comment: $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    remote: 'path/to/url'
}).on('typeahead:opened',function(){$('.dropdown-menu').css('width',$(this).width() + 'px');});

Comment: check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Emc/1/) out. I updated my fiddle the event is not firing.

Comment: Are you using the "old" Twitter Bootstrap 2 plugin with the new Bloodhound suggestion engine: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/26

Comment: I exactly don't know but what I'm using is [this](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead). It is not specified what is he using