# Implement select2 for Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I wanted to implement `Bootstrap typeahead` with `select2`.

My ajax result in coming perfectly but i want to divide the results into respective blocks,
So how to implement into typeahead!

Answer (score 1):

*`[FIDDLE] = http://jsfiddle.net/mohalibala/J4Emc/
 Hope it helps you`*

Try update: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167246/typeahead-problems-with-bootstrap-3-0-rc1/18171568#18171568) out